# Jpype passing arguments to Java

Tags: java, python-2.7, jpype

I have a java programmer with following line

```
service.loadPropertiesForItems(Inbox, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Body));
```

Program calls classes and methods from external jars.

I want to write equivalent code in python which calls external jars like my java program does.
Using Jpype I implemented the code but it fails on following line

```
service.loadPropertiesForItems(inbox, ewsPkg.PropertySet(ewsPkg.ItemSchema.Subject,   ewsPkg.ItemSchema.Body))
```

Here PropertySet, ItemSchema are classes which I use from external jar.
ItemSchema.Subject and ewsPkg.ItemSchema.Body are class type

Running the code I get following error on line mentioned above -

```
service.loadPropertiesForItems(inbox, ewsPkg.PropertySet(ewsPkg.ItemSchema.Subject, ewsPkg.ItemSchema.Body))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py", line 79, in _javaInit
  self.__javaobject__ = self.__class__.__javaclass__.newClassInstance(*args)
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at src/native/common/jp_method.cpp:121
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share a working sample of executing class' function of a jar from Python using Jpype. I was not able to find a working sample, tried a couple of with options but fail with error 'not callable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Martin https://github.com/originell/jpype/issues/117

following code works well

```
ItemSchema = ewsPkg.ItemSchema
PropertyDefinition = ewsPkg.PropertyDefinition
Subject = ItemSchema.Subject
Body = ItemSchema.Body

args = JArray(PropertyDefinition)([ItemSchema.Subject, Body])
PropertySet = ewsPkg.PropertySet(args)
```